# Regex formulation for NotePad++ - Negating a string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a series of paragraphs in a block of HTML. Most are full of text with some hyperlink tags. Occasionally a paragraph is followed by a paragraph that contains only an image. So:

```
<p1>...text..<a>...</a>...text...</p>
<p2>...text..<a>...</a>...text...</p>
<p3><img></p>
<p4>...text..<a>...</a>...text...</p>
```

I'm trying to find a regex for Find/Replace in NotePad++ that will match a paragraph that is followed by a paragraph with that contains an image (I want to wrap them in a  tag).

This seems to correctly match a single paragraph and no more:

```
<p(?!.*<p)?(.*?)</p>
```

But as soon as I try adding anything that matches the following image paragraph, the regex starts matching backwards to encompass every paragraph before the image paragraph (i.e., from p1 to p3, instead of p2 to p3).

The solution needs to include the dot character matching newlines (I think, anyway. There are carriage returns in the paragraph text).

Comment: if you want `.` that matches newlines use `[\S\s]` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match the paragraph before a paragraph containing an `img` tag you could use

```
<p((?!</p>).)*</p>(?=\s*<p(.(?!</p>))*<img.*?</p>)
```

The `Regular expression` and `. matches newline` options should be checked.

Note that this may not work if there are nested `<p>` tags, and it assumes there is only space, which may include newlines, between the paragraphs.

If you want the paragraph with the `img` tag to be included in the selection use

```
<p((?!</p>).)*</p>\s*<p(.(?!</p>))*<img.*?</p>
```

Comment: @EpF. Apologies for not realising sooner that the `img` tags wouldn't be in the form `<img>`. I took your example too literally.